# Selenium 2.53.0 + Chrome 51.0.2704.106 does not work

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium

I´m using chromedriver-2.22.exe and Chrome 51.0.2704.106. WebDriver opens up the browser, but it stucks with **"data:,"** in the address bar.

Then, after a few seconds, the log shows Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed

I´m on Windows 7 x64, Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_77-b03).

What could be the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: My guess is you will have to use the correct chromedriver for the version of chrome you are using.

Comment: can you provide your code?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. I resolved it with adding a dependency to:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.5</version>
</dependency>
```